# Bit shifting to print bits changing an int in C?

Tags: c, integer, bit-shift, bit

I'm just trying to print out the bits of an integer, and it looks like the int is somehow getting changed in the process, but it also appears to be changing in-between calls, not in the middle of the function.
My function is:

```
void printBits(int bits){
    int i = 0;
    printf("BEFORE: %u\n", bits);

    while(i < 32){
        printf("%d", 1 & (bits >> i));
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("AFTER: %u\n", bits);
}
```

In my main, it's called here and then the program exits (primes[0] is just the int being used):

```
printf("\nBEFORE PRINTBIT: %u\n", primes[0]);
printBits(primes[0]);
printBits(primes[0]);
printf("AFTER PRINTBITS: %u\n", primes[0]);
```

and the output is:

```
BEFORE PRINTBITS: 3450182216
BEFORE: 3450182216
00010010010110011010010110110011
AFTER: 3450182216
BEFORE: 2900726784
00000000001010011010011100110101
AFTER: 2900726784
AFTER PRINTBITS: 2900726784
```

Nothing is called between calls of printBits, and as far as I can tell printBits isn't affecting the int. But somehow it's changing. Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can stop it?

Comment: Your loop will print bit 1 of `bits` 32 times. So I don't even understand how can you get this output.

Comment: Shifting *signed* integers is always going to be... *shifty* (sorry for the bad pun). Use *unsigned* integers instead.

Comment: Provide code that actually reproduces the problem you describe -- a [mcve].  The code you present does not produce the output you present, nor does it more generally exhibit the problem you describe.  We appreciate you keeping it small, but a *minimal* example is worthless unless it is also *complete* and *verifiable*.

Comment: "Any ideas on why this is happening" --> `primes[0]` is not valid.  Post `primes` declaration, initialization/assignment..

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that `primes` is a dangling pointer, pointing into a stack frame of some previously returned function (eg, you returned a pointer to a local var in some previous function and set `primes` to that result).  This is undefined behavior, but generally what will happen is that the memory on the stack used by `primes` is being reused by the frame for the first call to `printBits`, so gets modified by that call.